Flutter isar with freezed throws Unsupported type error while build runner
While using isar with freezed, getting Unsupported type error for copyWith getter method while build runner.
Here is the model class for which the build_runner is failing.
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'api_response_model.freezed.dart';

part 'api_response_model.g.dart';

@collection
@freezed
class ApiResponseModel with _$ApiResponseModel {

  const ApiResponseModel._();

  factory ApiResponseModel({
    @JsonKey(name: 'data') String? data,
  }) = ResponseModel;

  Id get id => Isar.autoIncrement;

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      _$ApiResponseModelFromJson(json);
}

Here is the error thrown while build_runner command.
Unsupported type. Please annotate the property with @ignore.
package:freezed_isar/api_response_model.freezed.dart:28:51
   ╷
28 │   $ApiResponseModelCopyWith<ApiResponseModel> get copyWith =>
   │                                                   ^^^^^^^^
   ╵


The type of copyWith function generated by freezed is not supported by isar. To ignore copyWith, you can use the @collection annotation of isar like this:
@Collection(ignore: {'copyWith'})

There will be a conflict.
When we create a collection for "isar" then it generates a "g.dart" file and when use fromJson (freezed) it also generate the "g.dart".
An alternate solution:
Use vs code's extension : dart data class generator

Create your isar collection like this:
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
part 'api_response_model.g.dart';

@collection
class ApiResponseModel {
  Id? id = Isar.autoIncrement; 

  @Index(type: IndexType.value)
  String? data;
}

Move your cursor on class Name and tap on hint icon (or press 'cmd + .') it'll show options to generate data class: 
Then tap on "Generate data class" then it'll create all the required methods for a data class like toMap(), fromMap(), copyWith(), toJson(), fromJson() etc.
The generated code will show two errors, one in "toMap()" and other in "fromMap(). To solve this, we need to modify the "id" parameter for both methods
Generated methods:
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id?.toMap(), 
      'data': data,
    };
  }

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ApiResponseModel(
      id: map['id'] != null ? Id.fromMap(map['id'] as Map<String,dynamic>) : null,
      data: map['data'] != null ? map['data'] as String : null,
    );
  }

Updated methods:
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'data': data,
    };
  }

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ApiResponseModel(
      id: map['id']?.toInt(),
      data: map['data'] != null ? map['data'] as String : null,
    );
  }

At last, just run the build runner command to generated g.dart file for isar. (this can be done before creating copyWith() functions).
Now, your data class is generated and it can be used for isar collection and data conversion also.

Modifying generated files are not recommended as, If we run again the command or regenerate the way mentioned (even for newly added files), generated files will be regenerated and the changes will loose. As well, generated files (.g.dart) are not pushed to the VCS for the best practices.

In the above solution: we are not modifying the generated files. We are just creating  some required functions like copyWith() within the model class not in g.dart files.

It was my bad that I understood, you mentioned to modify .g.dart file. Though, instead of going with this little lengthy process, using "ignore" param of Collection annotation resolves this issue.

Where did I mention modifying the g.dart file?
